# System V IPC Limitations

Tags: unix, networking

While I was reading about System V IPC, I found that they can not be used between process across machines. Why is that so?
Is there any way to use them across machines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are local in-kernel IPC primitives. I don't see how they can be networked.

SysV IPC doesn't really give you anything revolutionary except a set of synchronization and communication primitives which are reliable and provided by the kernel (so you don't need third party dependencies). They are also easily usable my multiple processes which are independently spawned..

I think the next question would be: Which (SysV) IPC primitives do you wish to use over a network?

For normal messaging there are third party solutions like zeromq and others. For distributed lock management and semaphores, things get a bit  more complicated (writing a DLM isn't easy) - you can get away by using filesystems, using a distributed database which supports locking, OpenMPI (if that's your thing), etc.

There's no easy solution for this unfortunately (and if someone can share their success stories, I'll be glad to hear too).